# c# Moq SetupSequence 2nd call returning null

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I am writing a unit test for a class where I am passing three calls to the same method, but with some different properties.

The calls in the class look like this

```
if (request.ClubLogo != null)
{
    var clubLogoUrl = await _fileStorage.StoreFileAsync(request.ClubLogo, teamInfo.ClubTeam.Club.NationalGoverningBody.Country.Iso.Replace(" ", string.Empty), teamInfo.ClubTeam.Club.ClubName.Replace(" ", string.Empty), FileType.ClubLogo, "clublogo", cancellationToken);

    _logger.LogInformation(clubLogoUrl);
    teamInfo.ClubTeam.Club.SetClubLogoUri(new Uri(clubLogoUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
}

if (request.TeamLogo != null)
{
    var teamLogoUri = await _fileStorage.StoreFileAsync(request.TeamLogo, teamInfo.ClubTeam.Club.NationalGoverningBody.Country.Iso.Replace(" ", string.Empty), teamInfo.ClubTeam.Club.ClubName.Replace(" ", string.Empty), teamInfo.ClubTeam.TeamName.Replace(" ", string.Empty),
        FileType.TeamLogo, request.EventReference.ToLower(), cancellationToken);

    _logger.LogInformation(teamLogoUri);
    teamInfo.ClubTeam.SetTeamLogoUri(new Uri(teamLogoUri, UriKind.Absolute));
}

var teamPhotoUri = await _fileStorage.StoreFileAsync(request.TeamPhoto, teamInfo.ClubTeam.Club.NationalGoverningBody.Country.Iso.Replace(" ", string.Empty), teamInfo.ClubTeam.Club.ClubName.Replace(" ", string.Empty), teamInfo.ClubTeam.TeamName.Replace(" ", string.Empty),
          FileType.TeamPhoto, request.EventReference.ToLower(), cancellationToken);

_logger.LogInformation(teamPhotoUri);
teamInfo.ClubTeam.SetTeamPhotoUri(new Uri(teamPhotoUri, UriKind.Absolute));
```

However, when I make the call to store the team logo, teamLogoUri is null, but clubLogoUri has the correct value.

In the test I am setting this up like this

```
_fileStorage.Setup(x => x.StoreFileAsync(It.IsAny<IFormFile>(), It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(), FileType.ClubLogo, It.IsAny<string>(), CancellationToken.None))
    .ReturnsAsync("http://www.someurl.com/1");

_fileStorage.SetupSequence(x => x.StoreFileAsync(It.IsAny<IFormFile>(), It.IsAny<string>(),
    It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), FileType.ClubLogo, It.IsAny<string>(), CancellationToken.None))
    .ReturnsAsync("http://www.someurl.com/1")
    .ReturnsAsync("http://www.someurl.com/2");
```

The reason there is two setups is because there is an overloaded method as per this interface

```
public interface IFileStorage
{
    Task<string> StoreFileAsync(IFormFile file, string country, string club, string team, FileType fileType, string containerName, CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    Task<string> StoreFileAsync(IFormFile file, string country, string club, FileType fileType, string containerName, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

I cant see what I have done wrong here as I have setup a sequence many times in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you are setting up sequence with `FileType.ClubLogo` while the following calls are `FileType.TeamLogo` and `FileType.TeamPhoto`, change it to `It.IsAny<FileType>()`, or setup separate calls.

Comment: I had it that way in the beginning and still had the same result.

Comment: Can you please post a full [mre] then?

Comment: In the morning yes as I will need to strip a lot out

Comment: no idea how \ why... must have been because it was late... but have come back this morning and tried this.. and its worked..  one of those seeing the wood though the trees moments

Answer (score 1):

You are matching the `FileType` argument against `FileType.ClubLogo` and in the second call you are passing `FileType.TeamLogo`. Use `It.Is<T>` with an expression to match both:

```cs
_fileStorage.SetupSequence(x =>
    x.StoreFileAsync(
        It.IsAny<IFormFile>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.Is<FileType>(f => f == FileType.ClubLogo || f == FileType.TeamLogo),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        CancellationToken.None))
    .ReturnsAsync("http://www.someurl.com/1")
    .ReturnsAsync("http://www.someurl.com/2");
```